# Array bug crashing the console

Tags: c++, arrays

I have no idea what is wrong here. The problem is with the array accessing the last element that contains the terminating code. When I use `i <= sizeof(arr)` as the limiter in the `for` loop, the 4 element list works, but the 3 element list crashes. If I replace it with `i < sizeof(arr)`, the 3 element list works but the last element in the 4 element list is ignored.

```
int arrayList(string arr[])
{
    int choice;

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= sizeof(arr); i++)
    {
        cout << i << ". " << arr[i-1] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Select a number from 1 to " << sizeof(arr)-1 << ": ";
    cin >> choice;

    return choice;
}
```

Here is a function that calls the array list, but crashes when the fourth element is accessed.

```
void titleScreen()
{
    system("cls");

    int choice = 0;

    do {
        string arr[] = { "New Game", "Continue", "Exit" };

        choice = arrayList(arr);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            newGame();
            break;
        case 2:
            continueGame();
            break;
        case 3:
            exitGame();
            break;
        default:
            choice = 0;
            cout << "Invalid choice." << endl;
        }
    } while (choice == 0);
}
```

Here is the segment that also calls the list, but it works correctly.

```
do {  
        string arr[] = { "Attack", "Guard", "Skill", "Item" };

        switch (arrayList(arr))
        {
        case 1:
            hero_act = hero->attack(foe);
            break;
        case 2:
            hero_act = hero->guard();
            break;
        case 3:
            hero_act = hero->skill(foe);
            break;
        case 4:
            hero_act = hero->item();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Action invalid." << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (hero->hp > 0 && foe->hp > 0);
```

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` is the size of `arr` in bytes, not the number of elements. And `arr` inside the `arrayList` function is a pointer, so that doesn't help you. Use `std::array` for unsurprising behaviour.

Comment: Any attempt at debugging should reveal this instantaneously...

Comment: Why did it work in one of them?

Comment: 'cause you were lucky enough, that your pointer type had 4 bytes? As much as elements in the array.

Comment: @luk32 Unfortunately I have yet to learn how to use a proper debugger.

Comment: I'd say now is the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string arr[];
sizeof(arr);
```

is not what you want, since it's seen by the compiler as

```
string *arr;
sizeof(arr);
```

This is a compile-time constant and would always return the same value (the value depends on the machine and compiler used) irrespective of how many elements are actually in the array.

Passing in the count as a parameter to the function (old C-style) is an option. However, if you always pass automatic arrays whose size is known at compile time, you could do this

```
template <size_t N>
int arrayList(string (&arr)[N])
{
}
```